# Add rails routing concerns before the resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm wanting to make a `product` resource `:locationable` (meaning, can be filtered by its location).

```
# routes.rb
concern :locationable do
  member do
    get 'location/:location_id'
  end
end

resources :products, concerns: :locationable, action: :index
```

The routes above create the following route:

```
/products/location/:location_id
```

However, I'm wanting it to put the location first in the route. For example:

```
/location/:location_id/products
```

I'm wanting to use concerns for this--not nested resources.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing it to

```
# routes.rb
concern :locationable do
  resources :products, only: :index
  member do
    get 'location/:location_id'
  end
end
```

Check out routing concerns from here https://gist.github.com/dideler/10020345.

Comment: That wouldn't allow me to use the `locationable` concern with other routes, such as `receipts`. The concern needs to remain flexible